# Change a tooltip content on hover over session times button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My ASP.Net webpage generates buttons with below codes

```
 <a id="1173766" val="248506" titletext="<b>Click to book online for ABC Cinemas</b><strong>$10 tickets </strong>: Preview Screening<br /><br />Seats Available: 35<br />Screening in Cinema 1" target="_self" href="https://localhost:6969/VenueTicketing/Start.aspx?sessionId=248506&amp;cinemaId=cbcc0921bb8e233ab9626690" class="tooltip" title="<b>Click to book online for ABC Cinemas</b><strong>$10 tickets </strong>: Preview Screening<br /><br />Seats Available: 35<br />Screening in Cinema 1">11:30am</a>
```

When I hover over session I see basic information about session like screen name and seats remaining. [Please see screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0mAL.jpg)

[image]

On hover over session I want to display real time seats remaining number, So i am making an ajax call to a function which send api request and get live seats remaining number.

I am trying to update seats remaining number on rendered page by using following java script code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function handler(ev) {
        var target = $(ev.target);
        var sessionid = target.attr('id');
        var sessionPOSid = target.attr('val');
        var TooolTipText = target.attr('titletext');

        target.attr('title', TooolTipText);

        if (sessionPOSid == "done")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (target.is(".tooltip")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '../WebService/Home_SessionTimes.asmx/GetSeatsRemaining',
                    data: "{sessionId: '" + sessionid + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        //alert(msg.d);
                        var n = TooolTipText.indexOf("Seats Available: ");
                        var t = TooolTipText.substr(n + 17, 3);

                        if (t.indexOf("<") >= 0) {
                            if (t.indexOf("<") == 2) {
                                t = t.replace("<", "");
                            }
                            else {
                                t = t.Substring(0, 1);
                            }
                        }

                        TooolTipText = TooolTipText.replace(t, msg.d);

                        $('#' + sessionid).attr('title', TooolTipText);
                        $('#' + sessionid).attr('titletext', TooolTipText);
                        //$('#' + sessionid).attr('val', "done");
                        target.attr('title', TooolTipText);

                        target.tooltiptext = TooolTipText;
                    },
                });
            }
        }    
    }

    $(".tooltip").mouseover(handler);
});
```

Above code updates the "titletext" field of  tag but does't change anything on "title" field.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Still stuck there? anyone please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by using qtip. Every time user hovers over div with 'sessiontimes' class, I make ajax call to generate tooltip text (that comes from server based upon session time).

This is my output now:

[image]

This is the jQuery code. you need to import qtip css and script files from their website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sessiontimes').qtip({
        style: { classes: 'qtip-bootstrap' },
        content: {
            text: function (event, api) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../SessionToolTip.aspx',
                    data: 'sid=' + $(this).children("a").attr("id"),
                    dataType: "text",
                })
  .then(function (content) {
      api.set('content.text', content);
  }, function (xhr, status, error) {
      api.set('content.text', status + ':' + error);
  });
                return 'Loading...';
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you may look at this post and see if the same answer could apply to your situation
[JQUERY Change Title not working with tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969723/jquery-change-title-not-working-with-tooltip)

Comment: its giving me an Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function error at   $('#' + sessionid).tooltip("option", "content", TooolTipText);

Comment: Could be related to a missing library, such as bootstrap.

Comment: i fixed it but still can't update tooltip. i was debugging it, as soon as it passed that statement it reverted back to old value.